# Eclipse PDT setup for Java Server Pages

Tags: java, eclipse

I have used Eclipse PDT for my PHP development project. Now, I am learning to code in JSP. Can I use Eclipse PDT for it? If so, what do I need to do to it for it to support JSP projects? Thanks.

note: I've already asked it in [SE Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30979/eclipse-pdt-setup-for-java-server-pages) but someone commented that it is not appropriate in that community.

Answer (score 0):

You use an Eclipse distribution geared towards PHP. It is possible to extend any distribution's functionality by installing plugins, because Eclipse is a plugin platform. But it can cause problems like plugin incompatibility with each other (see a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31916085/combining-eclipse-for-java-ee-and-cdt?lq=1).

So if you seek a solution with less possible problems, I suggest using a separate distribution - Web Tools (http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/), which comes with appropriate plugins installed. This way you will have two safe to use distributions who won't affect each other.